# Two lists into Table form

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

The first one is given by

```
xvalues = {75.618, 77.2612, 78.9044, 80.5477, 82.1909, 83.8341, 85.4774, 
87.1206, 88.7638, 90.0045, 91.2452, 92.4859, 93.7266, 95.6915, 
97.6563, 99.6212, 101.1, 102.578, 103.442, 104.306, 105.478, 106.649, 
107.241, 107.834, 108.426, 108.68, 108.933, 108.959, 108.984, 
108.991, 108.998, 108.999, 109., 109., 109., 109., 109., 109., 109., 
109., 109., 109., 109.}
```

The other one is given by

```
yvalues= {0.999907, 0.999932, 0.999953, 0.999969, 0.99998, 0.999989, 0.999994, 
0.999998, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
1., 1., 1.}
```

Can I somehow get these into a list on Table form such as {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2},...}?

Comment: `Transpose[{xvalues, yvalues}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Transpose @ {xvalues,yvalues}
```

or

```
Thread@{xvalues, yvalues}
```

both give

> {{75.618, 0.999907}, {77.2612, 0.999932}, {78.9044,
> 0.999953}, {80.5477, 0.999969}, {82.1909, 0.99998}, {83.8341,
> 0.999989}, {85.4774, 0.999994}, {87.1206, 0.999998}, {88.7638,
> 1.}, {90.0045, 1.}, {91.2452, 1.}, {92.4859, 1.}, {93.7266,
> 1.}, {95.6915, 1.}, {97.6563, 1.}, {99.6212, 1.}, {101.1,
> 1.}, {102.578, 1.}, {103.442, 1.}, {104.306, 1.}, {105.478,
> 1.}, {106.649, 1.}, {107.241, 1.}, {107.834, 1.}, {108.426,
> 1.}, {108.68, 1.}, {108.933, 1.}, {108.959, 1.}, {108.984,
> 1.}, {108.991, 1.}, {108.998, 1.}, {108.999, 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109.,
> 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109.,
> 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109., 1.}, {109., 1.}}